# how to stack EditTexts

Tags: java, android, textview

i made a game and added EditTexts for players names but I want to make it that if the players names are long that fills the width of the screen the names should stack above each other
note: the TextViews are generated using the java code

i tried asking chatgpt but it did not give me what i want and i searched for it in this site but the problem that the content of the TextViews changes so i dont know how to make it work

the code i use (if it would help)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout nameLayout = findViewById(R.id.names);

    String[] playerNames = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("player_names");

    for (String name : playerNames) {
        if (name.contains(",")) {
            String[] splitNames = name.split(",");
            names.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitNames));
        } else {
            names.add(name);
        }
    }

    String[] namesArray = names.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
        namesArray[i] = names.get(0).trim();
    }

    for (String name : playerNames) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setText(name.trim());
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        nameLayout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behavior by setting the android:layout_width property of the TextViews to "wrap_content" and setting the android:layout_weight property of the parent LinearLayout to "1". This will make the TextViews wrap their content and take up equal space within the LinearLayout.

Here's the updated code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayout nameLayout = findViewById(R.id.names);

String[] playerNames = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("player_names");

for (String name : playerNames) {
    if (name.contains(",")) {
        String[] splitNames = name.split(",");
        names.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitNames));
    } else {
        names.add(name);
    }
}

String[] namesArray = names.toArray(new String[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
    namesArray[i] = names.get(0).trim();
}

for (String name : playerNames) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(20);
    textView.setText(name.trim());
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            1
    );
    params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    nameLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

}

In the above code, we set the layout_width property of the TextView to "wrap_content" in the LinearLayout.LayoutParams constructor. We also set the layout_weight property of the LinearLayout to "1", which will make the TextViews take up equal space within the parent LinearLayout.

With this updated code, if the player names are too long and fill the width of the screen, the TextViews will stack above each other instead of overflowing horizontally.

Comment: there is still a problem that the names still dont stack but the some last letters of names gets under the name

Comment: i think i know why this is happening because every name has its text view so when the screen is filled parts of the text view stack but i want the whole text view to stack under each other.